# Prove that the set $S=\{B:Y⊆B⊆A$ and $F[B]⊆B\}$ is nonempty.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $F:A→A$ be a function and let $Y⊆A$.  Prove that the set $S=\{B:Y⊆B⊆A$ and $F[B]⊆B\}$ is nonempty.

I tried to say that any element $y \in Y$ is in $A$ and we can define the set $B$ such that $y \in B$, but I'm having trouble defining $B$ s.t. $F[B] \subseteq B$ based on the given info.

Comment: You just have to find one element in $S$. Which ones should you try for first?

Comment: Well I tried the $\emptyset$, but that doesn't work unless $Y=\emptyset$.  I then tried $B=Y$, and so for every $y \in Y$, $y \in B$.  Then i get stuck with the second condition, as every $F(y) \in B$.  But then $F(F(y)) \in B$, and this kind of alludes to the natural numbers, no?  I'm not sure how to prove it formally

Comment: Which obvious answer have you not tried yet?

Comment: oh it's just $Y=A$ isn't it

Comment: Exactly, that’s it!

Comment: Appreciate the help!  Since $Y \subseteq B$ if $B=A$ and since $F:A\to A$, $F[B] \subseteq B$.  Totally should have seen that.  Is there a problem if A is empty?  Edit: Nevermind, as S would then be: $S=\{\emptyset\}$

Comment: No. $S$ is a set of subsets of $A$ and $\emptyset$ is then a subset of $A$.